# Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal comic strip about aliens

Tags: story-identification, webcomics, saturday-morning-breakfast-cereal

I'm looking for a Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal comic strip/cartoon about aliens where the aliens say the world is a reality TV show where they adjust human hormones to see the effect it has on their relationships.

Comment: @Stormblessed, what was the point of the edit? There isn't any difference between the two forms, and I'm partial to the "Looking for"

Comment: the [story-identification] tag already states the question is looking for something; editing out "looking for" and the like removes redundancy and makes for a more informative title.See [this meta consensus on story-ID titles](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6453/98028)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it's [this one called "Coupling"](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/coupling)

[image: Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal - Coupling]

Found using the Google search `site:www.smbc-comics.com hormones`.

Comment: Yep. This is it.